# Как правильно создать иконки под андроид?

Tags: android, android-studio, icon, launcher

Сгенерировал иконки, но на рвзных телефонах они по разному отображаются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возникает вопросы:
1. Делать ли иконки квадратными и их лаунчеры сами обрежут как надо:
2. Или делать иконки под популярные лаунчеры, самому скруглять края, переименовав в round, circle, square.
3. В каком формате PNG, JPG, на прозрачном фоне или заливать?

**Буду рад любой информации.**

Comment: 1. Делайте не надеясь на обрезку. 2. Делайте обычную и круглую (запись в манифесте) . 3. Круглая не должна быть прозрачной в середине (из моих наблюдений) иначе уменьшит.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Самое простое решение - нажать правой кнопкой по пакету drawable(в res) и выбрать Image Asset.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее вы сами можете добавить иконку,посмотреть как она будет выглядеть на разных устройствах. Также можно добавить цвет и фон.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]